# 10.2 Dataset extraneous print using Transpose

Tags: bugs, dataset

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 10.2**
(by paclet update *GeneralUtilities 10.2.1*)

---

This is probably patch code in 10.2.  Is there a way to turn off print with `Transpose`?

```
ds = <|"k1" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, 
   "k2" -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>|> // Dataset
```

[image]

```
ds[Transpose]
```

> {a,b}{k1,k2}{{1,3},{2,4}}

[image]

This only affects `Dataset` :

```
ds // Normal // Transpose // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: `Block[{Print}, ds[Transpose]]`?  (Don't have V10.2 yet.)

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for reporting this, we're looking into it!

Comment: Update: We're looking into fixing this via an automatic paclet update in the next few days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a stop-gap, one can use `Block` to turn off `Print`:

```
Block[{Print}, ds[Transpose]]
```

Answer (score 12):

**Update**

This problem has been fixed by a paclet update -- specifically version 10.2.1 of the *GeneralUtilities* paclet:

```
PacletFind["GeneralUtilities"] // PacletInformation //
  GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations // Dataset
```

[image: paclet information screenshot]

In chat, Arnoud Buzing [stated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22900938#22900938) that this patch will normally be loaded automatically during the weekly paclet update.  He also offered the following steps to perform the update manually:

1. Evaluate these expressions:

   ```
   PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];
   PacletInstall /@ PacletFindRemote["WolframAutoUpdate"];
   PacletInstall /@ PacletFindRemote["GeneralUtilities"];
   ```
2. Quit and restart the kernel.

---

**Original Response**

As we await a fix from WRI, we can remove the errant `Print` as follows:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
DownValues[GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose] =
  DeleteCases[
    DownValues[GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose]
  , HoldPattern @
      Print[
        GeneralUtilities`General`PackagePrivate`ikeys
      , GeneralUtilities`General`PackagePrivate`keys
      , GeneralUtilities`General`PackagePrivate`vals
      ]
  , Infinity
  ]
```

Naturally, this will void your warranty...

Comment: :-) what are the involved risks ?

Comment: @chris Personally, I think the patch is perfectly safe.  But obviously WRI aren't going to support it.